# ASP.Net binding issue with different data

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, webforms

I have a form that has been working for a long time and today is only failing with my UAT database.

**View:**

```
<%@ Control /* ... */ %>
<asp:Panel runat="server">

   <!-- Area not visible, list disabled -->
   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='False'>
      <asp:RadioButtonList runat='server' id='lstTradingSameAsRegistered'
           AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="False" />
   </asp:PlaceHolder>

   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%#!GetCurrentValue(IsTradingAddressSameAsRegistered , lstTradingSameAsRegistered)%>'>
      <!-- ... -->
   </asp:PlaceHolder>

   <-- Area visible, list enabled -->
   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='True'>
      <asp:RadioButtonList runat='server' id='lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegisteredLabel'
           AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="True" />
   </asp:PlaceHolder>

   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%#!GetCurrentValue(IsHeadOfficeAddressSameAsRegistered , lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegistered)%>'>
      <!-- ... -->
   </asp:PlaceHolder>

</asp:Panel>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    lstTradingSameAsRegistered.Items.Clear();
    lstTradingSameAsRegistered.Items.Add("Yes", "True");
    lstTradingSameAsRegistered.Items.Add("No", "False");

    lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegistered.Items.Clear();
    lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegistered.Items.Add("Yes", "True");
    lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegistered.Items.Add("No", "False");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lstTradingSameAsRegistered.SelectedIndex = IsTradingAddressSameAsRegistered ? 0 : 1;
        lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegistered.SelectedIndex = IsHeadOfficeAddressSameAsRegistered ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

public bool? GetCurrentValue(bool modelValue, ListControl control)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        var result = Request.Form[control.UniqueID].TryParseAs<bool>();
        if (result.HasValue)
            return result;

        if (control.SelectedValue == "True")
            return true;

        if (control.SelectedValue == "False")
            return false;

        return null;
    }
    else return modelValue;
}
```

On Dev+Live database the code is working fine, but on UAT I get a `NullReferenceException` after calling `GetCurrentValue()` on a `PostBack`.

When I select a new item in `lstHeadOfficeSameAsRegisteredLabel`, a `PostBack` event is raised and in the view the selected item of the two `RadioButtonList` are `null`.

The source code of the project is the same, during my tests I only change the database path in the config file. I don't get any other error while debugging the page.

As this is only binding (I guess), what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you have same data in both DBs.May be some data is missing.

Comment: Except IDs data is the same for this specific page. If some data were I should get a different error message and should happen in my data layer. Instead my `RadioButtonList` containing static data is not binded.

Comment: Well I can't see any data access going on here. You seem to be missing some code - can you update your question and provide the code for `IsTradingAddressSameAsRegistered` and `IsHeadOfficeAddressSameAsRegistered` (these look like properties, perhaps this is where some data access is occuring ?)

Comment: Also - your OnInit looks odd. There's no overload of RadioButtonList.Items.Add that takes two string parameters. Is there an extension method somewhere ?

Comment: Yes that is an extension. I figured it out, the issue only happens when a variable is set to the future (similar to `DateTime` class  allowing to set a custom date without changing the date of the server). I don't understand the reason of the issue, and I have to find a workaround to allow my client to test invoices. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from a framework. I have a custom `DateTime' class in my application created to avoid to change the server date, and when this date is setted to the future that breaks the .Net binding in some parts of my application.
I don't have the entire source code of the framework so I cannot investigate more, but setting my custom date the same value as`DateTime` fixes the problem.